# How to do a fields query using query string search on elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I want to convert this query:

```
GET demo-index/_search
{
 "fields": [
 "*"
 ]
}
```

into something like this:

```
GET demo-index/_search?fields=*
```

is it possible to do fields queries in this way or a way similar to it without using a json body for the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [filter_path](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#common-options-response-filtering) :

If we've have the next return:

```
{
  "took" : 3,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 10000,
      "relation" : "gte"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "demo-index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "32223223d3e23dd23d2x23",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "username" : "Mike",
          "date" : "2022-04-04"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And we would like to return all fields,we should write the path as follows:

```
GET demo-index/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source.*
```

If we would like the specifics fields like "username", we should write the path as follows

```
GET demo-index/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._source.username
```

Comment: It doesn't return the fields present in index mapping. It just returns the original documents. I need the documents after mapping

Comment: I have updated the answer. I hope that It will be useful

Comment: Thank you for the update. However, I still can't get it to return the "fields" field. How's filter_path related to that?

Comment: You can get similar results as "fields" with filter path without using "fields" in the body.
As you can check in official documentation of Elasticsearch filter_path, the difference between filter_path and fields is that you should to write the path